# Android App Root detection method was bypassed by focusing specifically on the rootbeer library being used

Tags: android, rooted-device, xposed-framework, roottools, mobile-security

My Android App uses [rootbear](https://github.com/scottyab/rootbeer) library to detect rooted devices. But during app security penetration testing, **rootbear root detection** mechanism is bypasssed using the "**unrootbeer Xposed module script**"

Below are the steps followed during penetration testing:

Step 1 . Run application in rooted android device to see the error as it detects the rooted device.

Step 2. Run Jadx and check for root detected mechanism in place.
As we see the rootbeer method is being used.

Step 3. **Run unrootbeer Xposed module script by installing and activating** it in device.

Step 4. Now reboot the device and wait for activation.

Step 5. Open the application and the **application root detection mechanism is bypassed**.

I have also check other library [RootTools](https://github.com/Stericson/RootTools/wiki/Usage).
is **RootTools** library a suitable and up to date library for root detection ?

These are some of the questions:

1. How to **prevent** rootbear library **root detection bypass** ?
2. **Does obfuscation will help** to prevent such bypass ?
3. Is there any **other available root detection library** that cannot be bypassed ?
4. Is there any **better root detection** implementation **suggested by google** ?

Comment: Did you try to solve this please?